# Why does C# compiler not optimize simple async/await methods

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider the following two C# methods. While functionally equivalent, the first one seems to be better performing, as suggested by the corresponding IL instructions.

**Faster:**

```
static Task<string> Proxy(string text)
{
  return Foo(text);
}
```

[image]

**Slower:**

```
static async Task<string> ProxyAsync(string text)
{
  return await Foo(text);
}
```

[image]

From my understanding compiler under the hood replaces await instructions with a sophisticated state machine.

**Why is compiler not able to automatically optimize trivial cases like this?**
This seems like a low hanging fruit with large impact.

Also, what are the (dis)advantages of doing such optimizations manually in C# code (i.e. intentionally preferring the faster implementation over the slower).

Comment: Well, your methods are not equivalent. The first one is synchronous and the second one - asynchronous. Why would you expect the compiler to change the method type?

Comment: One major difference is that if `Foo()` throws synchronously, the first definition will pass the thrown exception up the call stack, and the second definition will return a faulted task object.

Comment: Also, [related blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) that I read recently. Has a lot of good information to compare examples like these and why omitting `async` / `await` might not always do exactly what you want or expect.

Comment: Don't force people to guess what `Foo` does. If it returns a task, make it clear eg by renaming it to `FooAsync`, or posting an actual definition for `Foo`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos while I generally agree with your suggestion, I think this question was premised on the assumption that it didn't matter how `Foo()` was implemented as long as its signature was `Task<string> Foo(string text);`. Part of the answer is pointing out that it does in fact matter.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that's not obvious from the code. It confused dymanoid and me.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually it _is_ obvious. Both definitions _require_ that to be the signature for `Foo()`, or it wouldn't compile. There's nothing ambiguous about the way the question is written, imo.

Comment: Apple and orange, you are just seeing that the C# compiler has to do some real work to implement async/await.  Inevitably, there is nothing in the CLR that helps to make it easier.  Focusing on *speed* is not very sensible, you write async code only *because* the operation is slow.  The handful of nanoseconds that the plumbing adds is never noticeable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does C# compiler not optimize simple async/await methods

Because every feature (including optimizations) [starts at minus 100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/). This is especially true if the semantics are different, *which they are in this case*.

The difference is subtle, but if you define `Foo` as:

```
Task Foo(string text)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

then the behavior of `Proxy` and `ProxyAsync` are different. `Proxy` would propagate the exception directly to the caller; `ProxyAsync` would capture that exception and place it on the `Task` returned from `ProxyAsync`.

I have a blog post that goes into more detail on [thoughts to consider when eliding `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Comment: Oy, shouldn't you be presenting on .NET Conf today? ;)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: And now I feel silly for writing an answer *not* linking to that post! :)